# Update angular list filter on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I can't figure out how to update an angular list after the filter is updated. The following is my code in the html:

```
<li ng-repeat="items in list | filter:filterList" style="list-style-type:none">
     {{items}}
</li>
```

And the following is my onClick event in the controller which changes the filterList variable:

```
.controller('inputter',function ($scope){
    $scope.inputCount = 0;
    $scope.list = ['red robin', 'testerastic', 'fantastic', 'blue jay'];
    $scope.filterList = '';
    $scope.addtolist = function(){
        if($scope.addtoform!==''){
            $scope.list.push($scope.addtoform);
            $scope.addtoform = '';
            $scope.inputCount++;
        }
    };
    $('.link').on('click',function(){
        var filterButton = '';
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            filterButton = '';
        }
        else{
            $('.nav > li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            filterButton =  $(this).text().split('Filter ').pop();
        }
        console.log(filterButton);
        if(filterButton!==''){
            $scope.filterList = filterButton;
        }
        else{
            $scope.filterList = '';
        }
        $scope.$live;
    });
  });
```

The filter DOES work, but only once I start typing into the input box below it which has a ng-model-instant method attached. The two test buttons I have set up have values 'Blue' and 'Red'

Comment: can you provide a fiddle/plunker/etc?

Comment: You're using jquery for events. angular doesn't know they're happening. Use `ng-click` and `ng-class` or use `$scope.$apply`

Comment: no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, no, jQuery DOM manipulation inside angularjs controller, everything inside the click function happens outside of angularjs so you lost the two-way data binding, what you need is to use scope.$digest/$apply or learn the angularjs way which will be more efficient

Comment: General rule of thumb: do not do DOM manipulation in your Angular controller.

Comment: @sxnine here is my fiddle, although I couldn't get angular to load properly, you get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/RpM5n/

Comment: Okay, I'll try using the ng-click methods, thanks for the tips @calebboyd

Comment: posted an answer with a working example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because jQuery operations happen outside of the $digest/$apply cycle, you'll need to manually $apply yourself. Like this:

```
if(filterButton!==''){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.filterList = filterButton;
    });     
}else{
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.filterList = '';
    });
}
```

This will force angular to update the data bindings. ALSO, you have another issue: when you pull the name of the filter you're getting a lot of additional whitespace that is preventing your desired functionality. To remedy this:

```
filterButton =  $(this).text().split('Filter ').pop().trim();
```

Notice that I've added `.trim()` to that line, that will strip the extra whitespace and your filter will work.

**Working plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/jDMCacspmUEnbVNOssV1

**Side note**: As many have stated in comments, you typically want to avoid doing DOM manipulation from within your controllers. With angular, you can use things called "directives" such as `ng-click` et al. Within these, there are link and compile functions where you are given access to the DOM elements at different points in the life-cycle.

Putting your DOM manipulation code in the proper place will ensure that angular updates everything at the right time. If you stick to the `$apply` method for EVERY case, you'll find that there are times when you're already within an `$apply` cycle and you'll be unable to manually `$apply` at that time.

I would look into directives and general information on how you can modify DOM within angular. The idea is to do as little DOM manipulation as possible. Within the large software project we're doing at work, we don't really need to do ANY DOM manipulation manually because directives like `ng-if`, `ng-class`, `ng-click` and a few custom directives handle that for us. All within angular's normal life-cycle.